# Get updates in Mainactivity every time BackgroundService trigger

Tags: java, android, inheritance, extends

I have

```
public class Backgroundservice implements AlarmReceiverCallback {
private Context context;

public Backgroundservice(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void onAlarmReceived() {
   //interface trigger
}}
```

now i would like to extends **Backgroundservice**  in my **MainActivity** class that extends **AppCompatActivity** .

so i can use my method inside the mainactivity once the interface in Backgroundservice get trigger

Comment: Why do you want to "extend" MainActivity?

Comment: no i want to extend backgroundservice class Inside the mainactivity

Comment: why do you want to do that?

Comment: well i have method that runs in the mainactivity class, i want to run it once the onAlarmReceived implements in Backgroundservice get triggered

Comment: you can extend only one class mate. would you be more specific what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: Why do you use AlarmReceiverCallback? Can you be more specific with what you want to achieve?

Comment: I Java a class can extend only one class, it's different from C++ (for example).

Comment: well you can user Broadcast Reciever to achieve that

Comment: okay so i have alarmservice that trigger lets say every 1hour, once i get call back from the alarmManager i call  AlarmReceiverCallback trigger = new Backgroundservice(context);
                    trigger.onAlarmReceived(); and then i send send API to get new Token. now the problem is i need to do my refresh token api in mainactivity so im trying to get trigger in mainactivity

Comment: Why do you need to do the "refresh token api" in your MainActivity? It seems like your application relies way too much on your activities.

Comment: because i would like to re-use the same code in multi apps so i need it to be more dynamic, i could have just set my method inside the Backgroundservice class but im trying to find way to reuse the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manged to get it working by creating new interface

```
public interface ReceiverCallback {
public void onReceived();}
```

and implements in my mainactivity, and than creating new object of it inside

```
    @Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BroadCastReceiver`

in you serveice class

```
public class Backgroundservice implements AlarmReceiverCallback {
    private Context context;

    public Backgroundservice(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAlarmReceived() {

       // send broadcast from here
       Intent intent  = new Intent("alaram_received");
       context.sendBroadcast(intent);
    }
```

and in your MainActivity receive this broadcast.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Register Receiver
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("alaram_received");
        registerReceiver(alarm_receiver,intentFilter); 
    }

    BroadcastReceiver alarm_receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            // refresh Token
        }
    };
}
```

Happy Coding.

Comment: Thanks this works, and i will have to find way to receive data when app is closed too